# How to implement the Fullcalendar TimeGrid View in Oracle Apex

Tags: fullcalendar, oracle-apex, fullcalendar-scheduler

I would like to implement the Fullcalendar Timegrid View (Premium paid version) in my Oracle Apex 19.1 application. I how this particular view is a paid version and I'm fine with that, the problem is that Apex does not have it implemented out of the box so I'm willing to get some instructions about how to do so, can anyone help?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc. If you're talking about a "premium" version of the timegrid then I guess you're referring to this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view?

Comment: yes, I'm talking about the premium version.

Comment: But, I'd like to know how I will use it on oracle Apex? Have I just include the links referred into "https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view"  in the page load section. Shall  I import the calendar same as mention about Webpack or Rollup?

Comment: On the surface, I think this will be a big job requiring a lot of knowledge and time to build/maintain (it may even be best as its own plug-in). I suggest you explore alternatives using native APEX features. But if you really want to pursue this path then contact someone for help, such as Max at https://askmax.solutions/

Comment: @MohammadHattab Sorry my knowledge is only of fullCalendar. I don't know what Apex is or anything about it, so I can't advise you specifically about that. But fullCalendar is just a browser-based application, and to use it you just have to ensure the right JavaScript libraries are loaded into the web page when it is served to the user. So, however you control/configure the loading of JavaScript libraries in the Apex system, I suggest you use that to ensure the right fullCalendar libraries are loaded in the page you are creating.